# how to add add a new variable to multiple data.frame at once without creating a list

Tags: r

If I have multiple data.frame in my environment with name _OK, and I would like add ID=1 into each of them. Is it a way that i can do it at once instead of one by one? I know that i can use mget to build a list for the data.frame ended with _OK. But I would like to know whether there is a way to skip the list. USing list, I will be ended up with two set of data.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do that in a `for` loop with `assign`

```
for(obj in ls(pattern = '_OK')) {
       tmp <- get(obj)
       tmp$ID <- 1
       assign(obj, tmp)
  }
```

---

Or another option is `mget` to return the datasets into a `list`, `transform` each element by looping over the `list` and update the objects in the global environment with `list2env`

```
list2env(lapply(mget(ls(pattern = '_OK')), transform, ID = 1), .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Can this be rewrote using `lapply`? If so, how? Many thanks.

Comment: @Stataq then you can list2env, but you said you don't want to get the elements into a `list`

Comment: @Stataq updated with `lapply`

Comment: @akun i try to skip to build a data list so i won't ended up with two set of data in the environment.list2env might work. :D.

Comment: @Stataq Then you may loop over the `ls` objects, use `get`, and do the `assign` as in the for loop i.e. `lapply(ls(pattern = "_OK"), function(obj) {tmp <- get(obj); tmp$ID <- 1; assign(obj, tmp)})`